# How to interact with DBs in external of a source code?

Tags: c++, com, odbc, registry, atl

How is it possible to interact with databases without using tranditionnal string connections into source code, but, do this in external of the source code?

I've heard that I can deal this using : ODBC and buffers(registry base).

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Write the string to a (xml, ini, json, ...) file or registry key?

Comment: Could you add some more details to your question? It is not entirely clear what you are asking.